# how to add a document each day in mongodb automatically

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mern

I am building a restaurant table reservation app using MERN stack, I need a collection in mongodb called reservation, that consists of documents having all reservations for each day. So a document must be created for each day, can I do the same automatically using mongodb or mongoose.

Comment: What if they were already there? 

Can't you insert them for the next 50 years or so?

This way, you save yourself some code to maintain. And race-conditions, single point of failure, etc...

Comment: that's a good idea, but won't it increase the database size

Comment: Yes it will increase your db size, but if these are empty docs, maybe that does not matter much. Try it out and check if it's acceptable ?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way for you to do such a thing is to write:

1. A controller that will create a new document with a date field [the date field will be StartOfTheDay [https://momentjscom.readthedocs.io/en/latest/moment/03-manipulating/03-start-of/].
2. A cronjob that will run on every night, maybe 12:01 AM?

With this setup, you can do it more flexible, controlling pre-defined input as-well as logging info in nodejs level

You can try looking into https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-cron